# AssertError not catched in unittest in python try-except clause

Tags: python, unit-testing, try-except

I have a object created in a test case, and want to make test inside of its method.
But the exception is swallow by the try-except clause.
I know I can change raise the exception in `run` but it is not what I want. Is there a way that any unittest tool can handle this?

It seems that `assertTrue` method of `unittest.TestCase` is just a trivial assert clause.

```py
class TestDemo(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_a(self):

        test_case = self

        class NestedProc:

            def method1(self):
                print("flag show the method is running")
                test_case.assertTrue(False)

            def run(self):
                try:
                    self.method1()
                except:
                    pass  # can raise here to give the exception but not what I want.

        NestedProc().run() # no exception raised
        # NestedProc().method1() # exception raised
```

---

**EDIT**

For clarity, I paste my realworld test case here. The most tricky thing here is that `ParentProcess` will always success leading to `AssertError` not correctly being propagated to test function.

```py
class TestProcess(unittest.TestCase);

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_process_stack_multiple(self):
        """
        Run multiple and nested processes to make sure the process stack is always correct
        """
        expect_true = []

        def test_nested(process):
            expect_true.append(process == Process.current())

        class StackTest(plumpy.Process):

            def run(self):
                # TODO: unexpected behaviour here
                # if assert error happend here not raise
                # it will be handled by try except clause in process
                # is there better way to handle this?
                expect_true.append(self == Process.current())
                test_nested(self)

        class ParentProcess(plumpy.Process):

            def run(self):
                expect_true.append(self == Process.current())
                proc = StackTest()
                # launch the inner process
                asyncio.ensure_future(proc.step_until_terminated())

        to_run = []
        for _ in range(100):
            proc = ParentProcess()
            to_run.append(proc)

        await asyncio.gather(*[p.step_until_terminated() for p in to_run])
        for proc in to_run:
            self.assertEqual(plumpy.ProcessState.FINISHED, proc.state)

        for res in expect_true:
            self.assertTrue(res)
```

Comment: Yes, all `assert*` methods raise an `AssertionError` which can be caught. Perhaps you want to let the test `.fail()` directly.

Comment: As @deceze said, add an `except AssertionError` to catch it and then `fail()`.

Comment: __NEVER__ use a bare except clause.

Comment: But in my code base the class is complex and the exception is handled and return to other process. I just want raise the exception here in the unittest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any `assert*` method and even `fail()` just raises an exception. The easiest method is probably to manually set a flag and `fail()` afterwards:

```
def test_a(self):
    success = True

    class NestedProc:
       def method1(self):
           nonlocal success
           success = False
           raise Exception()

       ...

    NestedProc().run()

    if not success:
        self.fail()
```

Comment: Great! That what I am looking for. However, my real case is a bit more complicated (as shown in my edited question). I wonder is there any built-in way provide by unittest or maybe other test tool can directly throw the exception to outermost test function. Anyway, the flag way compromisely solve my problem.